# Hide Load more Ajax button if there is no more users to load or less than the number?

Tags: ajax, javascript, pagination

How to hide the Load more Ajax button if there is no more users to load or less than the number

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
var page = 2;
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.loadmorefollowing', function() {
            var data = 
            {
                'action': 'user_following_by_ajax',
                'page': page,
                'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("user_more_following"); ?>',
                'author': '<?php echo esc_html($curauth->ID); ?>'

            };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        $('#following-artists-cont').append(response);
        page++;
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this may work, if `response` is just HTML and returns an empty string `''` when there are no more results:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
    var page = 2;
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('body').on('click', '.loadmorefollowing', function() {
            var data = 
                {
                'action': 'user_following_by_ajax',
                'page': page,
                'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("user_more_following"); ?>',
                'author': '<?php echo esc_html($curauth->ID); ?>'

                };

            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                if ( '' === response ) {
                    $('.loadmorefollowing').hide();
                    return;
                }

                $('#following-artists-cont').append(response);
                page++;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```